# How to debug smooth color change in processing?

Tags: processing

I have written code in which the stroke color should transition smoothly through red, orange, yellow, green etc. in a loop. The rest of the code works perfectly but I am having issues attaining the color transitions.

It's expected that the Red value increases by 1 until it reaches 255, where it stays as the Green value does the same. Then the Red value should begin the decrease by 1 whilst the Green remains at 255.

The issue with the code is that the Red and Green values will both increase as necessary, but no matter what I try, I can't get the Red value to decrease.

Any input will be greatly appreciated. Please note I believe the issues lie in the code block at the end after the line marked //color transitions.

```
float xNoise, yNoise;
float angle = -PI/2;
float radius;
int red = 0;
int blue = 0;
int green = 0;
int redValue = 1;
int greenValue = 1;
int blueValue = 1;
int colorMode = 1;

void setup(){
  size(800, 600);
  smooth();
  frameRate(24);
  background(0);
  noFill();
  
  angNoise = random(10);
  radiusNoise = random(10);
  xNoise = random(10);
  yNoise = random(10);
}

void draw(){
  radiusNoise += 0.005;
  radius = (noise(radiusNoise)*550)+1;
  
  angNoise += 0.005;
  angle += (noise(angNoise)*6)-3;
  if(angle > 360){ angle -= 360; }
  if(angle < 0){ angle += 360; }
  
  xNoise += 0.01;
  yNoise += 0.01;
  float centerX = width/2 +(noise(xNoise)*100)-50;
  float centerY = height/2 +(noise(yNoise)*100)-50;
  
  float rad = radians(angle);
  float x1 = centerX + (radius*cos(rad));
  float y1 = centerY + (radius*sin(rad));
  
  float opprad = rad + PI;
  float x2 = centerX + (radius*cos(opprad));
  float y2 = centerY + (radius*sin(opprad));
  
  //color transitions
  stroke(red, green, blue, 60);
  strokeWeight(2);
  ellipse(x1, y1, x2, y2);

  //color mode 1 (red)
  if (colorMode == 1){blueValue = -1;
  if (red == 255 && blue == 0) {colorMode++;}
  if (red == 0) {redValue = +1;}
  red += redValue;}

  //color mode 2 (green)
  if (colorMode == 2){redValue = -1;
  if (green == 255 && red == 0) {colorMode++;}
  if (green == 0) {greenValue = +1;}
  green += greenValue;}

  //color mode 3 (blue)
  if (colorMode == 3){greenValue = -1;
  if (blue == 255 && green == 0) {colorMode++;}
  if (blue == 0) {blueValue = +1;}
  blue += blueValue;}
  if (colorMode > 3) {colorMode =1;}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here's a code snippet to demonstrate a way to accomplish this:

```
int blueDelta = 1;
int blue = 0;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
}

void draw() {
  updateColorDelta();

  background(color(0, blue, 0));
}

void updateColorDelta() {
  switch (blue) {
  case 0: 
    blueDelta = 5;
    break;
  case 255:
    blueDelta = -5;
    break;
  }
  
  blue += blueDelta;
}
```

I'm sure you'll figure out how to add it to your business logic. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that once you drop into the `colorMode == 2` block, you stop updating the red color. So even though you set `redValue` to -1, you never actually apply it to the `red` value.

It might be easier to see if you indent those blocks:

```
//color mode 2 (green)
if (colorMode == 2){
  redValue = -1;
  if (green == 255 && red == 0) {colorMode++;}
  if (green == 0) {greenValue = +1;}
  green += greenValue;
}
```

You never update `red` so it never reaches 0 and you never meet the condition `green == 255 && red == 0`

A good way to debug this (what you actually asked), might be to simply print out the values at the end of your `draw` function so you can see what the values are:
`println(red, green, blue);`

From there it should be easier to see why your conditions are failing.